# Unable to identify the cause of this error: Exception has occurred: ParserError Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 51, saw 2

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, tabula

I am using tabula-py to read data from some pdfs, but keep getting this error.

Exception has occurred: ParserError
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 51, saw 2

The PDF i am reading from is almost exactly the same as the one that I built this code around. For example, I built it while testing with another PDF, and am now changing to a new updated one that is the same format and style, but the code now fails and throws this error.

Not sure what I am doing wrong / why this code that previously worked no longer works.

Code snippet:

```
tabula.convert_into_by_batch("-----", stream = True, output_format='csv', pages='11-57')

path = ("-------")

filenamelist = os.listdir(path)
updated_path = path+ "\\" + filenamelist[0]


new_frame = pd.read_csv(updated_path, skiprows=2, encoding='ISO-8859-1') #error thrown here
```

Comment: not sure if it is related to the error, but instead of join path 'by hand' you should do it using `os.path.join(path,filenamelist[0])` different os uses different symbols to path and a code that runs in linux may fail in windows

Answer (score 1):

The conversion of pdfs to csvs is no perfect transformation. Converting anything away from a pdf is actually quite difficult and can be finnicky no matter what library you're using. Your error is telling me that on line 51 of your converted csv's there is a comma that `pandas` did not expect to see. So in all of the rows leading up to the "bad" row, you only had single commas (e.g. it expected to see 1 value). Then on row 51, it encountered either 2 values, or a value with a comma at the end, which makes this an improperly formatted csv.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

bad_csv_file = io.StringIO("""
A
1
2
3
99
50,
100
""".strip())

pd.read_csv(bad_csv_file)
```

**output**

```
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 2
```

Note that there's an extra comma on line 6 that leads to the above error. Simply removing that extra trailing comma resolves this error.